# Response from UrlConnection Java

Tags: java, urlconnection, http-response-codes

So far, I have this snippet.

```
URLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (new URL("some_link")).openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

The possible response codes are 200 and 404 and it's working fine when the response code is 200 (OK). My question is how can I find the response code received by my connection, for example: if the response code is 404, throw an exception and do smth there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it to a type of `HTTPUrlConnection`. Then you can use `.getResponseCode();`

Answer (score 3):

use something like this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("URL_STRING")
                               .openConnection();


int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: `connection.setRequestMethod("GET")` is the default.